# Why do I get a 0 width for a class instantiated by static variable

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is a Monitor class. I am trying to get it's width, through it's static property. So that, to get width, I can write : Monitor.width, Monitor.height

However, when I instantiate, it through a static variable, the instantiation is successful, but still returns a 0 value width. Is their any alternative way ( other than instantiating it inside the get width and get height method itself ) ?

```
package {

import flash.display.*;

public class Monitor extends MovieClip {

    private static var staticInstance: Monitor = new Monitor(); 

    public function Monitor() {

    }
    static public function get width(): Number {
        // staticInstance: Monitor = new Monitor()  <<< this will work
        return staticInstance.width;
    }

    static public function get height(): Number {
       // staticInstance: Monitor = new Monitor()  <<< this will work
        return staticInstance.height;
    }
}
```

}

When trying :

```
trace(Monitor.width)  // output is 0
```

Comment: is your class Monitor have any children added? or maybe some code-generated visuals by "graphics" property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't do this with a display list type. Static code gets executed when your class gets initialized by virtual machine (i.e. in internal `Monitor$cinit()` method), and it will not create visuals for you. Try placing `trace(this.width);` in `Monitor` constructor and see that it returns zero with your approach.

If you are absolutely sure, that you need a singletone here (which is not the case most of the time), use the "classic" idiom:

```
package  
{   
    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class Monitor extends MovieClip 
    {
        private static var instance : Monitor;

        public static function getInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new Monitor();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public static function get width()
        {
            return getInstance().width;
        }

        public function Monitor() 
        {
            trace("Monitor constructor: "+this.width);
        }
    }   
}
```

When you do:

```
trace("Monitor.width = "+Monitor.width);
```

The output should be:

```
Monitor constructor: some_number
Monitor.width = some_number
```

Comment: @BotMaster Yeah, you posted just while I was editing. Effort wasted. :)

Answer (score 1):

That is correct since static variables are computed before anything else when your program starts so a graphic object can't really have any size at this point.
The correct way to deal with this is to delay the instantiation with a classic getInstance() for example:

```
private static var staticInstance: Monitor;
```

No instantiation to start with then:

```
static private function get instance():Monitor
{
    if(!staticInstance)
    {
        staticInstance = new Monitor();
    }
    return staticInstance;
}
```

Now use this getter in all your calls:

```
static public function get height(): Number 
{
    return instance.height;
}
```